# use of NSFilemanager

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am working as an Iphone developer since 5 months but never ever i have used NSfilemanager  class. Apple has documentation but still i am not cleared about its use. My question is that can anybody tell me(with example) how and when to use the NSfilemanager class ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

NSFileManager is used to perform read write operations on file, to save a file on your application.To check whether the specified file is present on that location or not.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
// Get the path to the database in the application package
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

// Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
```

this is an example for checking the file existing.